# Can I use a standard SMA connector and cable to deliver high voltage to a PCB?

Tags: pcb, connector, high-voltage

I'm designing a power circuit which I need to bring high voltage, ~3000V DC, into from an external power supply. Normally I would use an [SHV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHV_connector) connector, but they don't seem to offer these connectors in a form that can be mounted directly to a PCB.

Is it possible to just use a standard SMA cable/connector? I assume the connector would be fine as 3000V is not enough to arc from the sleeve to the pin, but I'm not sure about the cable itself.

Comment: What does the cable specification say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking through an old (2007, paper!) Farnell catalogue, I cannot see voltage ratings on any of their SMA connectors. However there are ratings on (dimensionally similar) SMB and SMC connectors of 250Vrms and 335Vrms, but no DC ratings.

This [SMA connector datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/106753.pdf) shows a dielectric strength of 1000V at 50Hz (*almost* DC!) and a corona extinction voltage of 250V, and a "working voltage" less than that.

I did find one RG174AU cable with a max DC voltage rating of 6kv between core and screen so with care, the cable may be up to it, but unless you have better luck selecting components than I did, the connector is likely to be a problem.

Comment: To summarize: No, do not expect an SMA connector to operate at 3kVDC.

Answer (score 0):

Given the very high voltage nature of your board, I highly recommend you contact the manufacturer of the SMA connector and cable and ask them about this.

Comment: Better yet, call your connector manufacturer of choice, explain what you're trying to do, and see what the application engineer recommends.

Answer (score 0):

Mount your PCB in a chassis and buy the chassis connectors.

Comment: This is an option, but I want the circuit to have a low profile and the SHV connectors are bulky.

Comment: @user545424 The reason voltages around 3kV are often not going to be simple surface mount is that the distance 3kV can arc is large enough an SMA connector will not give enough of a safety margin. A chassis mount will allow 3kV and ground to be far away from eachother.